# size of 2 dimensional vector

Tags: c++, vector, size, valgrind

I have been trying to figure out the size of 2 dimensional vector and not able to figure out entirely.

The test program that I have written is as below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> one(1);
    vector < vector<int> > two(1, vector <int>(1));

    return 0;
}
```

Memory allocation when I check with the help of valgrind is confusing me. After executing the first statement in the main block, I get the below output.

```
==19882==    still reachable: 4 (+4) bytes in 1 (+1) blocks
```

So far so good. But after running the next statement I get the below log.

```
==19882==    still reachable: 32 (+28) bytes in 3 (+2) blocks
```

Now this is confusing, I don't know how to justify the 28 bytes allocated.
If I change the second line as below

```
vector < vector<int> > two(1, vector <int>(0));
```

I get the below log

```
==19882==    still reachable: 32 (+24) bytes in 3 (+1) blocks
```

Kindly help in understanding how the memory is allocated.

Comment: What dose it print when you do `std::cout << sizeof(std::vector<int>);`?

Comment: Related: [Size of empty vector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27935802/size-of-empty-vector)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### tl;dr

The first case just shows the allocation for the (`int`) storage managed by the vector. The second shows both the inner vector's `int` storage, *and the storage for the inner vector object itself*.

---

So it's telling you this

```
vector<int> one(1);
```

allocates one block of 4 bytes.

It doesn't tell you about the automatic storage for the vector object itself, only the *dynamic* storage for the single integer: assuming `sizeof(int)==4`, this seems pretty reasonable.

Next it tells you this:

```
vector < vector<int> > two(1, vector <int>(1));
```

allocates two more blocks of 28 bytes in total.

Now, one of those blocks will contain the dynamic storage for the `vector<int>` - remember the previous instance was an automatic local - and the other block will contain the dynamic storage for the nested vector's single integer.

We can assume the second (single integer) allocation is a single block of 4 bytes, as it was last time. So, the dynamically-allocated `vector<int>` itself is taking 24 bytes in another single block.

Is 24 bytes a reasonable size for a `std::vector` instance? That could easily be

```
template <typename T> class vector {
    T* begin;
    size_t used;
    size_t allocated;
};
```

on a platform with 64-bit pointers and size_t. This assumes a stateless allocator, which is probably right.

Comment: using three pointers is another common implementation that also fits if using 64 bit pointers.

Comment: absolutely, it's just one example to demonstrate plausibility.